# Find out which usb port is which and how to disable them

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

I have a laptop with windows 8.1 installed on it. it has 3 usb ports which I need them disabled. Like when you insert any usb control devices like usb keyboards, usb flash memories or anything else, I don't want them to go on at all. Now in my home pc it was easy cause the usb ports where obvious in the windows device manager, but in this machine, on my laptop, it is not easy to do that, cause the laptop's self keyboard, camera, and a few other devices are connected using usb ports to the main board, and disabling such devices might render the whole system useless with a great chance (I have encrypted the file system, so if something like a bootable hard disk is disabled to use USB the system might not start up at all). Is there someway to know which one of the USB ports are the ones I am after (the ones that you can simply insert a flash USB stick), and how can I disable and later on enable them?

Answer (score -1):

go to Control panel, System, Devices Manager, Universal Serial Bus Controllers,

Right click on ....USB Enhanced Host Controller --Disable or Enable.

Comment: Yes, I did do that, but the unfortunate part is that I only want two of the usb ports disabled, and I need the other one for the mouse. Like I need the both USB3 ports totally disabled, and the lonely USB2 port enabled, but no matter what arrangement I have set for the USB devices in the places that you have mentioned as well, I can't get only one of the ports working, it is either all of them or none of them, including the camera, bluetooth and etc...